# Append to single element of array

Tags: javascript, loops, append

Having trouble where my ‘p’ element value is being appended to both ‘reviewer-meta’ blocks. I think the issue may be that in my append function the 'p' element is being appended to all the review-comment-wrap elements. How do I append only to the block where the element with the value B was removed?

```
<div class="reviewer-meta">
    <div class="author-attribute">Value A</div>
    <div class="author-attribute">Value B</div>
    <div class="review-comment-wrap">some value</div>
</div>

<div class="reviewer-meta">
    <div class="author-attribute">Value A</div>
    <div class="review-comment-wrap">some value</div>
</div>


function runProgram(){
    var theElements = $('.reviewer-meta').find('.author-attribute');

    $(theElements).each(function(){
        if(this.innerHTML == "Value B"){
            $(this).remove();   
        }
    });
    $('.review-comment-wrap').append('<p>New value</p>');
}
runProgram();
```

Comment: Because you're using assignment and not equality comparison, e.g., `=` vs. `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Common syntax typo. You wrote `=` instead of `==` :

```
if(this.innerHTML == "Value B"){
```